# An object as a private data member inside another object, is it cached when parent cached?

Tags: caching, object

I have an object like this:
class Obj_A{
   private $_obj_child;
   public function child(){
         return $this->_obj_child;
    }
}
So, if I use $x= new Obj_A,

```
$x->_obj_child is not accessible.
```

Instead, I need to use

```
$y= $x->child() can get all data in child object
```

In my cache functions, **I cached $x. Is the $_obj_child get cached?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. What use would the cache be if it wasn't. Your cached object would either have a default state, or be in an invalid one.

Comment: When call $x, the function child() is not called or called? if not, I guess not cached.